# Determining type conversion programmatically

Tags: javascript

I would like to find a way to *programmatically* (i.e. by writing code) find for what values of `x` we have the expression `x == null` evaluating to `true`.

Comment: Theoretically speaking, that would be impossible. The range of values that x can take is infinite. You'd have to look at the language specs, or use the process of elimination to only look at certain values which are good candidates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to (without prior knowledge of at least the basic JavaScript rules) be able to programmatically determine *all* values of `x` for which `x == null` is true. However, the following should show a pattern from which a heuristic can be derived:

```
var v = [null, undefined, false, true, -1, 0, 1, "", " ", "0", {}, []]
for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
   var x = v[i]
   alert(x + " == null? " + (x == null))
}
```

(This particular test case does cover all the times when it would be true.)

Similar tests can be done for `== false`, etc.

Happy coding.

---

See Ray Toal's answer for more suggestions of test values.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of knowing at least *something* about how JavaScript performs type conversions the way these conversions are applied over the operator `==` you would have to test every possible value against `null`, and the number of possible values are unlimited, so what you ask cannot be done.

With a little bit of knowledge you can break down the world of all possible JavaScript expressions into the following categories:

- undefined
- null
- true
- false
- 0
- negative finite numbers
- positive finite numbers
- negative infinity
- positive infinity
- NaN
- empty string
- a string full of whitespace
- a string with at least one non whitespace character
- an empty object
- an object with some properties

Test a representative value from each class against `null` and see what you get.

I assume from the way the question was phrased that you know the exact section in the ECMA-262 specification that defines, precisely, the semantics of `==`. ( Section 11.9.3 of [the 5.1 
spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) )